# Moving Woocommerce products with variations to another theme?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-bookings

I am trying to move my products to the new theme that I bought. I was using woocommerce 2.4.12 and try to migrate it to 3.3.5. I tried to use all kind of plugins and so on but it did not work out for me. What I think is because my products have a variations.

Theme name: Nitro

Woocommerce version(current): 3.3.5

Woocommerce version (old): 2.4.12

I am trying all the suggested methods using CSV, export products, selecting different export options and etc.

Any help will be appreciated.

Best regards,

Dimitar Georgiev

Comment: Here is a description of some of the changes made between 2.4.12 and 3.3.5: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/2.6.x-to-3.0.0-Developer-Migration-Notes. There is indeed a change that could easily break code dealing with product variations. Good luck!

Comment: @nydame Thank you for your comment that really helped a lot. After reading it we realized that the task will be impossible so we decided just to upload all of the products by hand :( thank you for the tip we will keep in mind for next time to update in time :)